# Validate AWS Client Certificate from API Gateway in SailsJS, behind Elastic Load Balance

Tags: amazon-web-services, sails.js, aws-api-gateway, public-key

I have a small API Gateway endpoint, that sends a Client Certificate to a backend server. This backend server runs on Sails behind an ELB. What I want to do, is to filter some of the routes in Sails, and the policy should look for the Certificate in the request, if it is not sent, then reject and if its (validating against the public Key) then allow it to continue.

In the docs of AWS API Gateway (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html), they suggest to use client-certificate-auth (https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-certificate-auth), but I can't find a way to use it on my Sails backend.

I've tried using serverOptions in Sails, but it crashes with:

```
error: TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
```

So I'm pretty much lost on this one. If anyone has experience with it, please advice :)

Thanks

Comment: Are you using something in front of Node, like Nginx, Apache, or HAProxy? If so, *that* can handle the certificate validation.  Is your backend server using SSL now?  If not, you'd need that, too, of course...

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the EC2 server is fronted by a Elastic Load Balancer (AWS ELB)

Comment: ELB doesn't support SSL offload with client certificates.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot does that mean that is not possible to validate the API Gateway Client Certificate if my instance is behind an ELB?

Comment: No, it means that you have to set your ELB to run in tcp mode to act as an L4 tcp load balancer and terminate your connections on the EC2 instances behind the ELB.  Of course, you still need to figure out how to configure Sails to validate the client certificate used by API Gateway.

Comment: @MikeDatAWS will try that.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 0:**
As mentioned in some of the comments - you'll need to change the ELB to be a classic ELB and load balance TCP on port 443 instead of HTTPS.

**Step 1:** you'll need to launch sails with HTTPS - the config looks something like this:

```
      http: {
        serverOptions: {
          requestCert: true,
          rejectUnauthorized: true
        }
      },
      ssl: {
        key: key.Body.toString(),
        cert: cert.Body.toString()
      }
```

So either `config/http.js` and `config/ssl.js`, or pass those to `sails.lift()`.

**Step 2:** run the middleware. - there are lots of different ways to do this, but since you say you only want to do it some routes, I'd create a policy that runs client-certificate-auth, or even possibly better, just call `req.connection.getPeerCertificate()` and check the things you want to check. No need to use an extra npm module when you don't have to.

Here's the policy documentation:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies